# How to remove SelectedItem by click on it?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Suppose I have selected an Item on a `DataGrid`, I can remove all the selected items using `UnselectAll`, but I'm wondering how can remove the selected item by clicking again on it.

**EXAMPLE**

1. User select item1
2. Selection changed event is firing
3. User click again on Item1 and the selection is removed

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality for this that I am aware of. You would need to handle this functionality in the code behind, by subscribing to the `PreviewMouseDown` event on the `DataGrid`. There are other ways you can handle this (i.e. attached behaviors, custom control, etc), but this way would likely be most straight forward. Once you get the idea, you can work on your own implementation.

Here's a simple example of how one may achieve this. Looks a bit long, but this is a complete working example. Please extract the parts you will need.

The basic idea is this:

1. Subscribe to the `PreviewMouseDown` event on the datagrid.
2. When the event fires, you need to find which item was clicked on.
3. To find the clicked item use the `e.OriginalSource` Property and then walk up the visual tree to find the DataGridRow, using the helper method `FindParentOfType` provided.
4. Once you have the row, its DataContext is the clicked on item.
5. Once you have your clicked on item, check if it is present in `SelectedItems` property of your DataGrid. If so, remove it.
6. If item is found and removed, make sure to use `e.Handled = true` so that the item doesn't get selected by datagrid on this same click. If not removing the item, don't do anything, just let the DataGrid select it.

**Xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <!--The items source is binding to whatever the datacontext is, 
                which is the Window DataContext set in the code behind-->
        <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                  PreviewMouseDown="DataGrid_PreviewMouseDown"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApp
{
    public class TestData
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
        public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<TestData> Data = new ObservableCollection<TestData>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            //Get some data
            Data.Add(new TestData { Prop1 = "Column11", Prop2 = "Column12", Prop3 = "Column13" });
            Data.Add(new TestData { Prop1 = "Column21", Prop2 = "Column22", Prop3 = "Column23" });
            Data.Add(new TestData { Prop1 = "Column31", Prop2 = "Column32", Prop3 = "Column33" });
            Data.Add(new TestData { Prop1 = "Column41", Prop2 = "Column42", Prop3 = "Column43" });
            InitializeComponent();
            //assign our collection to the Window DataContext
            DataContext = Data;
        }
        //this is where all the magic happens
        private void DataGrid_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
            DataGridRow row = findParentOfType<DataGridRow>(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);
            if(dataGrid != null && row != null)
            {
                //the row DataContext is the selected item
                if(dataGrid.SelectedItems.Contains(row.DataContext))
                {
                    dataGrid.SelectedItems.Remove(row.DataContext);
                    //mark event as handled so that datagrid does not      
                    //just select it again on the current click.
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }

        //This helper is used to find your target, which in your case is a DataGridRow.
        //In general, if you continue with WPF, I would suggest adding
        //this very handy method to your extensions library.
        private T findParentOfType<T>(DependencyObject source) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            T ret = default(T);
            UIElement parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(source) as UIElement;

            if (parent != null)
            {
                ret = parent as T ?? findParentOfType<T>(parent) as T;
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```